# Using visual studio c++ compiler in netbeans

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction, netbeans

I want to develop a few assignments in C++ on Windows, but Visual Studio does not provide a few user functions that make development a real pain to go without. Can someone help me with setting up the Netbeans C++ environment to use the same compiler that Visual Studio is using?

Comment: Why do you need to use the VS c++ compiler?

Comment: @Lonzo There are many reasons why one would need or want to use the VS compiler; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3753181/14302

Answer (score 6):

NetBeans supports so called Tool Collection Descriptors, which are XML files telling NetBeans how to work with specific compiler collection. By default descriptors for Cygwin and MinGW are shipped. But it should be possible to create your own descriptor for Visual Studio and install it into NetBeans.

See this tutorial: http://www.netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/toolchain.html

Answer (score 6):

I am currently writing a plugin/toolchain to use Visual C++ on Netbeans.
You can find the project called VCC4N [on source forge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcc4n/) or on [NetBeans plugins](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/42519/?show=true).

Comment: Does not seem to work with Netbeans 8... They probably changed the format

Comment: Yes Netbeans 8.1 has different API I need to fix it

Comment: The version 0.5 now works on NetBeans 8.2 and support VS2017 too.